# gatsby link is using the current address instead of using the root address

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I want to make some pagination, but I don't know why my gatsby link is automatically adding the current address then adding the `to={}`.

Imagine it like this:

I want to go `page2` from `page1`. So, I will use `Link to={page1}`  and the link should be localhost:8000/page1 instead what I get is localhost:8000/page2/page1

Here is the actual code. In `pagetemplate.js`:

```
export default function Program({ pageContext, data }) {
      const post = data.cockpitProgram
      const { previous, next } =  pageContext
```

```
    {previous && ( 

    <Link to={previous.title.slug} rel="prev"
    
    // className={ navLinkPrev}
    >
        <div
        //  className={ navPrev}
        >      
            <h3
            style={{margin:0,
            fontSize:"1em"}}
            >
                {previous.title.value}
            </h3> 
        </div>
        <div 
        // className={ navMobilePrev}
        >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="chevron-circle-left"></FontAwesomeIcon>
        </div>
    </Link>
    )}
```

In `gatsby-node.js`:

```
const pages = res.data.allCockpitProgram.edges
        pages.forEach(( post,index ) => {
          createPage({
            path: `/${post.node.title.slug}/`,
            component: program,
            context: {
              slug: post.node.title.slug,
              previous: index === 0 ? null : pages[index - 1].node,
              next: index === (pages.length - 1) ? null : pages[index + 1].node,
            },
          });
        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't set a slash (`/`) at the beginning, it takes the path as relative. In the example: `Link to={page1}` should be `Link to={/page1}`.

Your `pageContext` seems to work properly, you are fetching the previous and next page, however, you are not setting correctly the `<Link>`'s destination.

So, in the provided code use `` <Link to={`/${previous.title.slug}`} rel="prev"> ``.

Comment: first of all, thank you, but then why in my other code i don't need to that ? , while the only difference that i know is that i use function on this one and in the other is using class...

Comment: The difference doesn't rely on your type of the component (class or function) it always depends if your queried variable has prefixed the slash or not. Usually, when you get a `slug` variable is managed internally by Gatsby like a `/variable`, so it's recommended to check if your variable has a `/` or not before using `<Link>` component

Comment: @FerranBuireu Did `Gatsby` change `Link`'s API or something recently? There was a vid on YT, which didn't add a slash at the start, it worked. It doesn't work now. I have to add the slash.

Comment: I think the author of the vid, corrected his mistake but didn't bring it into our notice.